# $.getJSON and google fonts API stops working in internet explorer with jQuery versions greater than 1.4.4

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, google-font-api

I have spent almost the whole day trying to find a solution to this problem.

I have successfully written code to dynamically retrieve and display the whole lot of fonts using the Google fonts API and jQuery 1.4.4. (works in all browsers)

I have had to change jQuery to version 1.7.2 and unfortunately noticed that the code I wrote works well in all browsers except for Internet Explorer.

I did some testing and found that in Internet Explorer $.getJSON or $.ajax fail to load the JSON font data from Google when using jQuery versions higher than 1.4.4.

This is the code I am using:

```
$(function(){           

$.getJSON('https://www.googleapis.com/webfonts/v1/webfonts?key=XXXXXX', function(json) {

alert(json);

});
});
```

After some research I have tried this too:

```
$.ajax({
type: "get",
url: "https://www.googleapis.com/webfonts/v1/webfonts?key=XXXXXXXX",
cache:false,
dataType:'json',
success: function(data){
alert(data);
}
});
```

Both methods fail in Internet Explorer using any jQuery version greater than 1.4.4 - nothing happens.

Any ideas why?
Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be IE that is blocking connection to hosts outside of your site's domain. This is due to the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy). This is usually not a big deal with the latest and greatest browsers out there, although it can still occur with any browser. I tested your code using JSFiddle and it threw an error about same origin in Chrome 21.

Normally, the way to fix this is to use JSONP. Unfortunately, the Google Webfonts API does not support JSONP. The best way that I can think about getting that data cross-browser is to download the JSON using a server-side programming language such as PHP. From there, you can echo the JSON out to the page and use the `$.getJSON` function to grab that data locally on your server.

**EXAMPLE:** *fontApi.php* (local file on your server)

```
<?php
$json = file_get_contents('https://www.googleapis.com/webfonts/v1/webfonts?key=XXXXXX');
die($json); // prints JSON to the screen that jQuery can use
?>
```

Then use the following jQuery...

```
$.getJSON('fontApi.php', function(json) {
    //your code
});
```

Hopefully this helps you out :)

Comment: It is a shame that I can't just use jQuery. Mixing it with php complicates things for what I am trying to do. I appreciate your help and I see how the problem can be caused by the same origin policy however it is strange that the above issue happens only with jQuery above version 1.4.4 (with jQuery 1.4.4 everything works fine). I would have thought that a browser's same origin policy would block remote urls no matter what jQuery version used. Maybe in jQuery 1.4.4 there is a way around this  same origin policy. Would be interesting to know what it is. Anyway, thank you, I will try your code :)

Comment: No problem! It is quite odd that it would work with jQuery 1.4.4 but not the latest versions. If that is the case, maybe you should stick with the older version. But you are totally right about that. It might be a bug somewhere causing it.