# Joomla module development - Reading/processing JSON data from file stored in module folders

Tags: php, json, joomla, joomla2.5

I am in the process of developing a module that requires JSON data stored on a file within the folders of the module.

Initially I was using a link to the remote JSON file and that worked fine... until I realised that using this method doesn't work on certain servers configurations and causes [issues with certain versions of jquery and IE](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11874617/1586079).

The obvious solution to this issue is to read the file locally within the joomla module however I am getting 403 Forbidden errors on the php file that is serving the json data (see below).

The file with the JOSN data is a php file with this code:

```
$json = file_get_contents('https://www.googleapis.com/webfonts/....');
die($json);
```

I am calling the JSON file using jQuery:

```
$.getJSON('....', function (json) {....}
```

Would anybody know how to go around this issue?
Thank you in advance for the help.

Comment: I'm not clear here - is your end goal to have a Google font available for use on the Joomla page your module is displaying on?

Comment: It sounds like you are having an issue retrieving the php file from your own server, so we will definitely need to see the full JSON call in jQuery to help you.

Answer (score 1):

```
$json = file_get_contents(JPATH::base() . 'modules/my_module/myfilewithjson.php');
echo $json;
exit();
```

if the file is not local then you should be using curl to get the contents.