# getJSON not working on IE

Tags: jquery, json

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var timezone = "GMT";
  var num1 = Math.random();
  $.getJSON("http://178.79.191.15/json.php?num="+num1,
    function(data){
        console.log(data.hour);
      if (data.hour == 0 || data.hour == 1 || data.hour == 2 || data.hour == 3) {
        $('#pokerform').show();     
      } else {
        $('#wrongtime').show(); 
      }
    })
});
```

The above is my function, it's working on Chrome/FF but not in IE.

I've set up `header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');` on `http://178.79.191.15/json.php`

What could be the issue?

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more about how it isn't working? What error do you get?

Comment: @Blender No errors, when I look in the IE developer tools I can see that for some reason it's not fetching the JSON url at all.. I can see it downloading jquery from google, but nothing afterwards

Comment: @Click Upvote that's why I'm using the num1 thing

Comment: @hoverhand I don't think that jQuery supports cross-domain Ajax requests in IE.

Comment: Read here: http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/8283

Comment: I had a [similar issue](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11874617/1586079) which i solved using the method in the answer given

Comment: try with `$.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });`

Answer (score 1):

You have a few issues:

For JavaScript you should use `===` instead of `==`, especially when checking against the value of 0. You are also missing a semi-colon to close out your `$.getJSON();`.

Here is the revised code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var timezone = "GMT",
        num1 = Math.random()
    ;
    $.getJSON("http://178.79.191.15/json.php?num=" + num1, function(data) {
        console.log(data.hour);
        if (data.hour === 0 || data.hour === 1 || data.hour === 2 || data.hour === 3) {
            $('#pokerform').show();
        } else {
            $('#wrongtime').show();
        }
    });
});​
```

Comment: You do know that JSON data is all strings by default? So he will have to do parseInt() on it all before he could compare it to integers using ===

Comment: Although I understand why you think that, you're actually technically wrong, as JSON can differentiate between value types. Read up on value at: http://json.org/.

Comment: strange, whenever i pass something from my php to JSON, it seems to convert everything to strings. May be its just php's json_encode function

Comment: Or may be its just for data fetched from the database, php treats them as strings even when they're ints and thus they're converted to strings in my code

Comment: Yes, that is why I understand why you had that impression, because most languages and storage devices treat JSON as string by default.